# subquery in FROM must have an alias POSTGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, table-alias

I am trying using the following query on a POSTGIS (Postgres) Database. The original question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313252/postgis-sql-query-filter-by-bounding-box

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) 
FROM ( 
 SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, 
        array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features 
   FROM (
     SELECT 'Feature' As type, 
     ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geom)::json As geometry, 
     row_to_json((id, name)) As properties 
  FROM lines As lg
  WHERE lg.geom && 
      ST_SETSRID(
        ST_MakeBox2D(
            ST_MakePoint(p_BB_XLong_MIN_3857, p_BB_YLat_MIN_3857),
            ST_MakePoint(p_BB_XLong_MAX_3857, p_BB_YLat_MAX_3857)),
      3857))
) As f) As fc;
```

However, i am getting the following Error:

```
subquery in FROM must have an alias
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you did not count `(` and `)` correctly.
Remove 1 `)` right before `As f` and that should be ok.